# Mongod command not persisting

Tags: mongodb, permissions

When I run `mongod`

This line returns

`all output going to: /usr/local/var/log/mongodb/mongo.log`

but it is immediately followed by my prompt again.

In my `mongodb.log` file the error reads

```
Thu Nov  7 10:44:55.968 [initandlisten] info preallocateIsFaster couldn't run due to: couldn't open file /usr/local/var/mongodb/journal/tempLatencyTest for writing errno:13 Permission denied; returning false
Thu Nov  7 10:44:55.968 [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 13516 couldn't open file /usr/local/var/mongodb/journal/j._0 for writing errno:13 Permission denied, terminating
Thu Nov  7 10:44:55.968 dbexit:·
```

Comment: Yeah, I ran `chown -R <username> /data/db`

Comment: yes. i did the install with homebrew then, the set up data directory section. which includes, `sudo mkdir -p /data/db` and `sudo chown 'id -u' /data/db` where `id -u` is my username

Comment: I believe I may have tried the manual install at one point in the past, maybe it still exists and there are overwriting issues?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's definitely a permissions issue as `errno:13` describes.

Try `sudo mongod`